# codeigniter, uri routing and subcontrollers

Tags: php, codeigniter

not sure how to do this... i have an controller name admin- and i want to use the controllers in a subfolder as "sub" controllers

i.e when a user visits mydomain.com/admin they are redirected if they are not logged
and if they visit mydomain.com/admin/customers they are also redirected but the actual customers class is stored in controllers/admin/customers.php

i want the admin controller to handle the check if logged in and add on the header template?

how can i route this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try extending the base controllers

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->auth->logged_in()) 
        { 
            redirect('login'); 
        }
    }

}


class Customer extends MY_Controller {

// if the user isn't logged in they will be redirected

}
```

I cite once again [Phil Sturgeon](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY)